# ReactJs Download a file from local folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have this code :

```
var link= document.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("download",name);
link.href=uri;
link.target="_blank";
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
link.remove();
```

Here I am passing -

```
url ="M:/folderfname/filename.xlsx";
name = "filename.xlsx"
```

I am getting this error:

> Not Allowed To Load Local Resource file://M:/folderfname/filename.xlsx

I am not getting how can I resolve this in react. Or is there any alternative to download file ?

**Note**: this is not about downloading a single file which I can import and download. FileName to download getting generated dynamically.

Comment: First off, you should not use direct DOM manipulation like `createElement` in React code if you can. Secondly, as the error states, you cannot use local filepaths. Put the file into the `public` folder of your React app and reference it from there. Like `/filename.xlsx`

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to access the local file system in your browser app without explicit permission. One of the browser's primary functions is to prevent this.

You can take a look at the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API) for progress in this area. Alternatively, you can operate a web server on your device and communicate with it in your app, using it as a proxy to access the file system. Because you are already writing JavaScript, I suggest that you explore [Deno](https://deno.land/) and [Node](https://nodejs.org/) for the server approach.